# Evaluate and assign variables inside ssh session in shell script

Tags: shell, unix, ssh

I'm trying to increment indx and eindx values inside a ssh session.but none of commands are working..

```
#!/bin/bash
hosts=( #10.xx.xx.xx )
PdidPrefix1=$1
Runtime=$2
indx=$3
eindx=`expr $indx + $4`
logfilename=$5
for i in "${hosts[@]}"
do
echo $i
ssh centos@$i << EOF
for var in {1..4}
do
indx=`expr $eindx + 1` // not working
eindx=$((indx+eindx))  // not working
done
EOF
done
exit
```

tried using let also

let "indx=indx+1" //not working

Kindly suggest best way to handle variables.

Comment: Have you tried quoting the heredoc sigil, (e.g. `'EOF'`) to prevent variable expansion on the local host?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin..Tried 'EOF' getting error.

Comment: Quoting the sigil prevents both *pathname* and *variable* expansion. It is a standard way to prevent both. It appears the problem you are having is you want the variables expanded locally and then the results pass via ssh to the host at `$i`. While not the cause, using `$((...))` arithmetic is correct, leave `expr a + b` in the past. Have you tried with `$((...))` arithmetic in all instances where you are doing math?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin used $((..)) expression ,however it did not work.If I am using `EOF`,it is throwing an error that it cannot resolve $var which i'm trying to use in another command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
hosts=( xx.10.20.30 )
PdidPrefix1=$1
Runtime=$2
indx=$3
eindx=`expr $indx + $4`
logfilename=$5
for i in "${hosts[@]}"
do
echo $i
ssh centos@$i "bash -s --  '$indx' '$eindx'" <<\EOF

echo "In remote shell with parameters $1 $2..."
indx=$1
eindx=$2

for (( var=1; var<=4; var++ ))
do

indx=`expr $eindx + 1`
eindx=$((indx+eindx))
echo "var=" $var " indx=" $indx " eindx=" $eindx
done
EOF
done
exit
```

Comment: No Luck.If I use \EOF, inner for loop variable 'var' is not getting resolved.If I remove and try to run, I can see in debug,expr $eindx + 1 is getting executed but not getting assigned to indx variable .

Comment: my bad..bro..Its working...I copied some part of code snippet and trying..Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

I have run the same script. And it shows the proper value.